# button.click not working after two remove append actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple shopping list app in html5.

Here is the behavior that works as I want:

You can click on the `$donebutton` and it moves the item from `#tbdlist` to `#donelist`. If you did this accidentally, the `$undobutton` will move the item back to the `#tbdlist`.

Here is what should happen next:

When I click on the `$donebutton` a second (third, fourth) time, it should move it back from #tbdlist to `#donelist`, but it doesn't. The `$donebutton` stops working. I think the `$delbutton` also stops working.

Can someone help me understand what is going on and how to fix it. I think it has something to do with scoping. The `.click` functions are all on one level, and the second time around we are "inside" the `$donebutton.click` function, but this makes no sense to me since the variables are declared on the top level. If the variable even exists, its methods should exist.

Thanks in advance,
Omar

HTML:

```js
$('form').submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
    var $delbutton = $('<li><button class="delbutton">x</button><br></li>');
    var $listitem = $('<div></div>')
    var $donebutton = $('<li><button class="donebutton">' + $('#itemname').val() + '</button></li>');
    var $itemname = $('<li>'+ $('#itemname').val() + '</li>');
    var $nameday = $('<li>yourname</li><li>datetoday</li>');
    var $undobutton = $('<li><button class="undobutton">^</button><br></li>');
    var $doneitem = $('<span class="added"></span>');
    //var $doneitem = $('<div></div>');
    $listitem.append($donebutton);
    $listitem.append($nameday);
    $listitem.append($delbutton);
 $('#tbdlist').append($listitem);
 $('input').val('');
    $donebutton.click(function() {
        $doneitem.append($itemname);
        $doneitem.append($nameday);
        $doneitem.append($undobutton);
        $("#donelist").append($doneitem);
        $listitem.remove();
    });
    $delbutton.click(function() {
        $listitem.remove();
    });
    $undobutton.click(function(){
    //var $delbutton = $('<li><button class="delbutton">x</button><br></li>');
    //var $donebutton = $('<li><button class="donebutton">' + $('#itemname').val() + '</button></li>');
        $nameday = $('<li>yourname</li><li>datetoday</li>');
        $listitem = $('<div></div>')
        $listitem.append($donebutton);
        $listitem.append($nameday);
        $listitem.append($delbutton);
        $('#tbdlist').append($listitem); 
        $doneitem.remove();       
    });

});

function archive() {
    $('#donelist .added').remove();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 alert("its on");

});

/* Jquery load test
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}
*/
```

```css
.hdr {
 text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: lightblue; /* yellow */
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}
#main{
 text-align: center;

}
#tbdlist {
  text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#donelist {
  text-align: center;
  /*font-weight: bold;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#tbdlist li { 
 width:25%;
} 

#donelist li   { 
  width:25%; 
} <span class="code-comment">/* 4 col */</span>

#tbdlist ul, #donelist, ul{
  width:760px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#tbdlist li, #donelist li{
  line-height:1.5em;
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
/* {
 border-color: red;
}
*/
button {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Shopping List App</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="hdr">
  <h2 class="titleid">Shopping List App</h2>
 </header>
 <div id="main">
  <ul id="tbdlist">
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Addedby</li>
   <li>Date</li>
   <li>Undo</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div class="adder">
   <form>
   <input type="text" id="itemname" name="Item" Placeholder = "An Item"/>
   <br>by: username <br>
   on: today's date <br>
  </form>
  </div>
  <button onclick="archive()">Archive</button>
  <ul id="donelist">
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Doneby</li>
   <li>Date</li>
   <li>Reget</li>  

  </ul>
 </div>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem you may be having is that by using the same jQuery object, passing it into append will *remove* it from its current location in the DOM, not add a new element. You're also using id's for elements which appear more than once on a page, when those should really use classes.

Basically, your click handler should requery the DOM for the elements each time, not simply reference the same jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(selector).click(function() {

});
```

to

```
$(document).on('event', 'selector', function () {

});
```